# PHP: instancia dinámica de clases, almacenar instancia en objeto de clase diferente al original

Tags: php, poo, class

Tengo un script para escanear un directorio con un archivos php de clases dentro, y almacenar en un objeto de clase todos los archivos escaneados:

```
$ABS = scandir(ABSDATACLASS, 1);
foreach ($ABS as $key => $name) {
    if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
        CORE::$ObjClassABS['DATA'][$name] = ABSDATACLASS . $name;
    }
}
$ABS = scandir(ABSLISTCLASS, 1);
foreach ($ABS as $key => $name) {
    if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
        CORE::$ObjClassABS['LIST'][$name] = ABSLISTCLASS . $name;
    }
}
```

Es imprescindible utilizar esta arquitectura ya que prácticamente todo el proyecto la utiliza y no puedo hacer un cambio tan grande.

el resultado de la matriz(Objeto de Clase) de: `CORE::$ObjClassABS`

```
array (
  'DATA' => 
  array (
    'class.userdata.php' => 'C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/t1/class/classabs/data/class.userdata.php',
    'class.proddata.php' => 'C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/t1/class/classabs/data/class.proddata.php',
  ),
  'LIST' => 
  array (
    'class.userlist.php' => 'C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/t1/class/classabs/list/class.userlist.php',
  ),
)
```

Lo recorro para hacer el `require File` el archivo, incluye Script:

```
foreach (CORE::$ObjClassABS['DATA'] as $key => $Class) {
    require_once $Class;
}
foreach (CORE::$ObjClassABS['LIST'] as $key => $Class) {
    require_once $Class;
}
```

cuando tengo todo el archivo requerido, necesito instanciar todas las clases, ya que este es un cargador de clases dinámico que necesito almacenarlo en una clase de objeto para reutilizarlo en cualquier lugar, el objeto de clase para rellenar es en donde guardo las instancias y me permite llamar a las funciones de cada clase: `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS`

```
foreach (CORE::$ObjClassABS['DATA'] as $key => $name) {
    if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
        $name  = basename($name);
        $name  = preg_replace('#\.php#', '', $name);
        $names = explode(".", $name);
        foreach ($names as $key => $namesr) {
            $names[$key] = ucfirst(strtolower($namesr));
        }
        $name          = implode('_', $names);
        $NamesClass    = $name . 'Manager';
        $InstanceClass = strtoupper(preg_replace('#\Class_#', '', $NamesClass));
        CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS'][$InstanceClass] = $this->$InstanceClass = new $NamesClass();
    }
}

el resultado es:

array (
  'ABS' => 
  array (
    'USERDATAMANAGER' => 
    Class_UserdataManager::__set_state(array(
    )),
    'PRODDATAMANAGER' => 
    Class_ProddataManager::__set_state(array(
    )),
  ),
)
```

y puedo invocar cualquier función en cualquier lugar con este código de ejemplo (en este punto no tengo problemas):

```
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['PRODDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameA();
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['USERDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameB();
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['USERLISTMANAGER']->FunctionNameC();
```

Pero pero se nos ohace muy dificil recordar el indice de la clase especifica `['USERLISTMANAGER']` para llamar luego a las funciones que deseamos.

Entonces me veo en la necesidad de presentarlo finalmente en el mismo objeto pero con un indice distinto,para Cambiar la forma en que llamo a la función a un solo indice del objeto, como este ejemplo (este seria el alcance deseado):

```
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameA();
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameB();
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSLISTMANAGER']->FunctionNameC();
```

he intentado con dos script de los cuales no he tenido resultado, supongo por el desconocimiento de como manejar los resultados en un objeto de clase y de instancia

Intenté agregar este alcance con un bucle para obtener este trabajo, pero no funciona, no puedo cambiar mucho el código:

```
CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER'] = new stdclass();
foreach (CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS'] as $key) {
    if (strpos($name, 'ABSDATAMANAGER') !== true) {
        CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER'] = extends (CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS'][$key]);
    }
}
```

**Error:** `syntax error, unexpected 'extends' (T_EXTENDS)`

Con este script perdí la accesibilidad a las funciones .:

```
$TempArray = [];
        foreach (CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS'] as $key => $name) {
            if (strpos($key, 'ABSDATAMANAGER') !== true) {
                $TempArray = array_merge($TempArray, (array) CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS'][$key]);
            }
        }
        CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER'] = (object) $TempArray;
```

nuevo Error: `Call to undefined method stdClass::ProdData()`

**¿Qué debo implementar en función del código que tengo para extender una clase sobre la marcha, sin tener que realizar cambios en la arquitectura?**

Comment: Admito que no entendí del todo el problema, pero me pregunto ¿por qué no usas `AutoLoader`? Es que leí algo como que querías recordar las clases para instanciarlas ... El meollo del asunto, que pones en negrita: **¿Qué debo implementar en función del código que tengo para extender una clase sobre la marcha, sin tener que realizar cambios en la arquitectura?** No se logra entender, ¿podrías explicarlo mejor?

Comment: no se usa `autoloader` por que este proyecto es grandisimo y no se utilizo al inicio, no puedo decirte quien o por que se tomo esa decisión. Segundo las clases ya están instanciadas eh incluso están guardadas dentro de un objeto de clase por lo cual me permite llamar a una funcion con el ejemplo: `CORE::$ObjClassInst['ABS']['PRODDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameA();` pero al final el segundo indice ['PRODDATAMANAGER'] es distinto para cada clase; lo que se busca es poder guardar todas las instancias en un solo indice sin sobre escribir las instancias anteriores.

Comment: ¿Que las clases están instanciadas? ¿Cómo así? eso es muy raro.

Comment: intente hacer merge de los objetos y nada de esto funciona o soluciona el problema. por eso la pregunta es bastante especifica, que debe implementar en el código existente que me permita tener el alcance deseado.

Comment: esta linea: `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS'][$InstanceClass] = $this->$InstanceClass = new $NamesClass();` Intancia una clase y la guarda en un objeto de forma dinámica. es lo que me permite hacer llamados a la funciones dentro de ellas.

Comment: es cmo hacer esto: `$obj = new stdObject();` para luego llamar funciones
`$obj->name = "Nick";` pero de manera dinamica por archivo y desde cualquier lugar usando un objeto de la clase `CORE` por eso se guarda como lo vez.

Comment: busco que las funciones que accedo en una clase, puedan ser accesible utilizando otra clase (Indice Generico) por eso trate de solucionarlo con extends. pero no resulto.

Comment: si tengo 2 clases ejemplo: `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['PRODDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameA();` y la otra `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['USERDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameB();` busco la manera de accesar las funciones mediante otro indice del objeto:  `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']['ABSDATAMANAGER']`  me falta el paso previo como pasarlas de un lado al otro, sin sobre escribirlas.

Comment: es como si quisiera hacer un merge de todas las funciones de clases distintas y llevarlas a una única clase.

Comment: incluso intente esto:`$obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $obj1, (array) $obj2);` pero no me sirve ya que los objetos tienen metodos.

Comment: @Xerif tengo un objeto en donde guardo múltiples clases `CORE::$ObjClassInstABS['ABS']`, cuando termino de instanciarlas quiero clonar sus metodos a una sola clase, para que el acceso a esos métodos sea mediante la nueva clase.

Comment: @Xerif ok, bueno hay otro post relacionado a este armado de clases, ya que ando en busqueda de dierentes soluciones, o una que sirva y a lo mejor el otro pueda ser mas practico pero esta en el foro en ingles.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190554/build-a-class-programmatically-from-files-and-current-class-or-in-new-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final tube que hacer unos cambios grandes para solucionar este problema de Clonar una clase o llevar las funciones de una clase a otra.

y lamentablemente no pude o no encontré la manera correcta de clonar métodos entre clases PHP al dia de hoy no lo permite.

pero encontré otra solución:

1. Primero tuve que eliminar las clases de los archivos a los que se les hace el `require`.
2. Debí crear una clase manejadora, en cual se debe realizar el require.
3. finalmente quien me ayudo fuen la funcion magica `__call()` que se encarga de tomar las funciones de los archivos incrustado por decir así asignarla a la clase padre.

En fin esta es la clase final, que hace el trabajo sucio (fucionar funciones de diferentes archivos dentro de una sola clase):

```
<?php
final class Class_AbsdataManager {
    public function ABSGetdata() {
        $ABS = scandir(ABSDATACLASS, 1);
        foreach ($ABS as $key => $name) {
            if (strpos($name, 'class.') !== false) {
                CORE::$ObjClassABS['DATA'][$name] = ABSDATACLASS . $name;
            }
        }
        foreach (CORE::$ObjClassABS['DATA'] as $key => $functionfile) {
            require_once $functionfile;
        }
    }
    function __call($functionName, $args) {
        if (function_exists($functionName)) {
            return call_user_func_array($functionName, $args);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

metodo de acceso por objeto de clase:

```
CORE::$ObjClassInst["MVC"]["ABSDATAMANAGER"]->ABSGetdata();
```

y despues puedo hacer desde cualquier lugar llamados a los metodos de los archivos:

```
CORE::$ObjClassInst['MVC']['ABSDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameA();
CORE::$ObjClassInst['MVC']['ABSDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameB();
CORE::$ObjClassInst['MVC']['ABSDATAMANAGER']->FunctionNameC();
```